# How do I call methods in a view controller on the press of a button in it's parent view controller?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have an iPhone app which has a tabBarController as the root view controller in mainwindow.xib.

One of the tabs has a class of UINavigationController and its View is loaded from an external Nib file currently called secondView.xib

How can I get a UIBarButtonItem which is on the NavigationController in the mainwindow.xib file to trigger methods in its child view, secondView.h/m view controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, all I needed to do was double click the subview within the navigation controller so it had focus, then ctl-drag it to the button I had placed on the bar and I could select the method from the drop down list.  Apologies if I wasted anyones time, thanks for the help anyway.  Both helped me look harder at what I was doing.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to get access to the app delegate (secondView app del) in the MainWindow and then call methods on that. Er, send messages to that object.

Answer (score 1):

Completely re-did the answer, since I misunderstood your question.

In the `viewDidLoad` method of the UIViewController add:

```
UIBarButtonItem *myButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] init]; // do some initialization here
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = myButton;
[myButton release];
```

The designated initializer for a `UIBarButtonItem` lets you set the method that's called when it's pressed.

Comment: @kubi It's actually the other way round I want.  My tabBarController has a tab which has a class of navigation controller.  I want to press a button on the upper left corner of the navigation controller which triggers a method in the child view controller